# Is it possible to write soap message to a xml file?

Tags: java, xml, soap

I've a soap message and I need to create an XML file which will include that soap message and I want to store that file in my local directory to send the file to the client later. Is it Possible using java. If so, than how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to prepare soap message.

If you are using `javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage` then this class has a method `writeTo(OutputStream)`. You can provide a `FileOutputStream` to output the soap message in the file.

Answer (score 2):

If the message is

1. a string, then use `FileWriter` to write it to a file with '.xml' extension.
2. a `SOAPMessage` object, then use `writeTo()` to write it to a file stream.
3. a `JAXBElement` object, then use a `Marshaller` to marshal(deserialize) the object to a string and then write it to a file following the method in point 1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Its a SOAPMessage and I'm now able to write it to a file stream using writeTo() method.